Ionic styling problems with inputs, icons, items
Applying styles to Ionic elements does not appear to adhere to the documentation, or follow a consistent approach. Here is the template section:
<ion-item class="monkey-ion-item">

  <!-- User Input -->
  <ion-input
    labelPlacement="floating"
    [placeholder]="placeholder"
    [type]="showPassword ? 'text' : type"
    class="monkey-input"
    [maskito]="type === 'tel' ? phoneMask : null"
    [maskitoElement]="type === 'tel' ? maskPredicate : null"
  >

  <!-- Label -->
    <div slot="label" class="monkey-input-label">
      {{ label }}
      @if (required===true) {
        <ion-text>*</ion-text>
      }
    </div>
  </ion-input>

  <!-- Optional Icon -->
  @if (iconPath) {
    <ion-icon
      class="monkey-icon"
      slot="end"
      [src]="iconPath"
      (click)="showPassword = !showPassword"
    />
  }

</ion-item>

Here's some concrete observations:
ion-input
.monkey-input {
  /** Apply to All Variants / Defaults */
  @extend .text-medium;

  height: 50;
  --padding-start:10px !important;  // must be important?! 
  --padding-end: 40px;              // works

  --border-width: 4.5px !important; // no effect
  ...
}

.monkey-icon {
  font-size: 26px;
  position: absolute;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
  cursor: pointer;

  // none of this colour stuff works
  --color: blue;
  color: blue;

  --color: "primary";
  --color: var(--text-and-lines);
}

ion-icon {
  // --color: "primary";
  --color: var(--text-and-lines);
}

Questions

Why does padding-start need !important? Yet padding-end does not?
I can't find any way of altering the colour & width of the divider line.
Also, what are the options for changing the icon colour. It appears to be stuck with the colour encoded into the svg (which is a custom one). I even put color="primary" into the ion-icon - no change. And wrapped it in a div with color:blue; Now change. It feels like I'm going slightly mad when working with ionic components. They refuse to do what you tell them.

Updates
On question 3, seems I need to change the fill of any element I want to recolour to fill=currentColor". My fault for not understanding how this worked.

Might as well share my findings.
First thing. It seems impossible to work with the ionic line which is part of the ion-item, So, you need to remove it:
<ion-item
  class="monkey-ion-item"
  lines="none">

Having done that, you can add a simple bottom border and style it like this:
.monkey-ion-item {
  height: 62px;
  --min-height: 60px;
  --padding-start:0; // overrides default
  --background: transparent;

  // Border when not in focus
  &::part(native) {
    border-color: var(--dark-gray);
    border-bottom-width: 1px;
  }
  // Border when in focus!
  &:focus-within::part(native) {
    border-color: var(--text-and-lines);
    border-bottom-width: 1.5px;
  }

N.B. I noticed some really odd things happening with an ion-input inside an ion-item. Depending on the custom CSS properties, occassionally 2 lines would appear. Changing height and --min-height played a part in this.
